# Return previous datas from database

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I made a posting-commenting app, where I want to display 2 comments only, and allow users to tap the "older comments" to show more 2 older comments

---

**The problem is, that whenever I try to return older comments while another user is just recently commented, then it returns invalid values**

```
id       | comment       | time     | 
---------|---------------|----------|
1        | "hello"       | 10:30    |
2        | "test"        | 11:00    |
4        | "test"        | 12:00    |
6        | "test"        | 13:00    |
```

PHP code

```
$startIndex = 0;

$qry = $db->prepare('SELECT --comment datas--
  ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT : startIndex, 2');
$qry->bindParam(':startIndex', $startIndex, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$qry->execute();

$comments = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$comments = array_reverse($comments);
```

**So let's say I've loaded the last comments (ID 6, 4)**

Then someone adds a comment..

```
id       | comment       | time     | 
---------|---------------|----------|
1        | "hello"       | 10:30    |
2        | "test"        | 11:00    |
4        | "test"        | 12:00    |
6        | "test"        | 13:00    |
100      | "NEW"         | 20:00    |
```

Now, if I want to return older messages than (6, 4), aka (2, 1), I call the PHP file

```
$startIndex = 2;

$qry = $db->prepare('SELECT --comment datas--
  ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT : startIndex, 2');
$qry->bindParam(':startIndex', $startIndex, PDO::PARAM_INT);
...
```

**then it returns (ID 4, 2)** :C

---

Is there a way to stick to the last loaded comment, and return older comments?

> How I define the $startIndex?
>   When a user first views a post, then the startIndex is 0 for the
>   comments. If the user clicks "previous comments", then it will be 2
>   (0+2) and I save it in the app as a variable. When the user clicks it
>   again, then it will be 2+2, and so on..

Comment: How do you define `$startIndex`?

Comment: @chris85 When a user first views a post, then the startIndex is 0 for the comments. If the user clicks "previous comments", then it will be 2 (0+2) and I save it in the app as a variable. When the user clicks it again, then it will be 2+2, and so on..

Comment: Why don't you store the last ID they saw, then you can use a `where` to select the records before/after the record they last saw.

Comment: You can also add 1 to $startIndex everytime a new comment is posted

Comment: Yeah I know I could do "WHERE id < :lastViewedCommentId", but then think about it.. What if that as an admin, I add a comment with higher ID than the lastViewedCommentId?

Comment: The requestor would still want to be looking at comments before the one they last saw, no?